CI/CD in Teams Toolkit with GitHub actions
I’m having troubles setting this up with the GitHub CI CD Template, user account is not recognised in directory despite setting up and confirming creds. With the GitHub secrets for M365 account can I confirm the following format:
M365_ACCOUNT_NAME: “user.name@org.Microsoft.com”
M365_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD: “your-password”
M365_TENANT_ID: 
# This is just an example workflow for continuous deployment.
# You should customize it to meet your own requirements.
name: 'Continuous Deployment'
on:
  # When new commits are pushed onto the main branch.
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  buildAndPublish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # You can uncomment the line below to use environments (refer to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments). 
    environment: pkb-environment
    env:
      AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{secrets.AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}}
      AZURE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.AZURE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}}
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}}
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: ${{secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID}}
      M365_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{secrets.M365_ACCOUNT_NAME}}
      M365_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.M365_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}}
      SECRET_BOT_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.SECRET_BOT_PASSWORD}}
      TEMAS_APP_UPDATE_TIME: ${{secrets.TEMAS_APP_UPDATE_TIME}}
      FUNCTION_APP_KEY: ${{secrets.FUNCTION_APP_KEY}}
      FUNCTION_APP_URL: ${{secrets.FUNCTION_APP_URL}}

      BOT_ID: ${{secrets.BOT_ID}}
      TEAMS_APP_ID: ${{secrets.TEAMS_APP_ID}}
      BOT_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_RESOURCE_ID: ${{ secrets.BOT_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_RESOURCE_ID}}
      BOT_DOMAIN: ${{secrets.BOT_DOMAIN}}
      TEAMS_APP_TENANT_ID: ${{secrets.TEAMS_APP_TENANT_ID}}
      M365_TITLE_ID: ${{secrets.M365_TITLE_ID}}
      M365_APP_ID: ${{secrets.M365_APP_ID}}
      TEAMS_APP_PUBLISHED_APP_ID: ${{secrets.TEAMS_APP_PUBLISHED_APP_ID}}
      
      AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME: ${{secrets.AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}}
      RESOURCE_SUFFIX: ${{secrets.RESOURCE_SUFFIX}}

      TEAMSFX_ENV: dev
      APP_NAME_SUFFIX: dev

      TEAMSFX_ENV_NAME: 'dev'
      TEAMSFX_CLI_VERSION: 2.*
      CI_ENABLED: true
  
    steps:
      # Setup environment.
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '18'
          
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      # Build the project.
      # The way to build the current project depends on how you scaffold it.
      # Different folder structures require different commands set.
      # 'npm ci' is used here to install dependencies and it depends on package-lock.json.
      # If you prefer to use 'npm ci', please make sure to commit package-lock.json first, or just change it to 'npm install'.
      - name: Build the project
        run: npm ci && npm run build
     
     
      - name: Deploy to hosting environment
        uses: OfficeDev/teamsfx-cli-action@v1
        with:
          cli-version: ${{env.TEAMSFX_CLI_VERSION}}
          commands: deploy
          env: ${{env.TEAMSFX_ENV_NAME}}


I am getting error:
(✖) Error: Failed to Execute lifecycle deploy due to failed action: azureAppService/zipDeploy. GetPublishingCredentialsError:Unable to obtain publishing credentials of app 'ME***' in resource group '***'
The account has contributor permissions on the subscription in Azure.

Could you try using a service principal rather than a user account to login to Azure, which is more recommended in CICD?
You could explicitly add a login step like this before your deploy step.
For your case, login Azure account into teamsapp cli in non-interactive mode requires disabling MFA, I think that could be the reason of your failure.
